# Flutter Firebase My old code suddenly does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Below code is for fetching some data from Firebase in my Flutter project.

This worked well before but suddenly it doesn't work.

When I put the break point at every single line, I found that it doesn't enter into ".then(DOES NOT READ INSIDE)"

Here is what I have tried until now

1. try-catch prase

: I put below codes into try{}, and tried to see anything from catch{}, But the code in catch{} wasn't able to be read.

2. .onError(), .catchError(), .whenComplete() method

: I put ".onError(), .catchError(), .whenComplete()" method after ".then()", But the code after ".then()" was not able to be read too.

3. Git

: When I do the checkout(sourcetree) to the point that I completed this part before, all the codes are exactly same with now.

Please give me some advice that I can try or solution...

```
DocumentSnapshot oldestDocID = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('NewCardsList')
          .doc(cardManagementProvider.newCardsIDList.last)
          .get();
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('NewCardsList')
          .orderBy('timestamp')
          .endBeforeDocument(oldestDocID)
          .limitToLast(_theNumberOfFetchingOldCard)
          .get()
          .then((value) async {   // only can read until here
        value.docs.forEach((element) {
          docIDList.insert(0, element.id);
        });
        cardManagementProvider.addAtLastOfNewCardIDs(docIDList);
        for (var i = 0; i < docIDList.length; i++) {
          await FirebaseService.getCardData(context, cardID: docIDList[i]);
        }
      });
```

Comment: I was facing the these kind of issues earlier, read docs and that resolved my problems

Answer (score 0):

### [Firebase with flutter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) is updated lot more that we used to know.

You need to update all of your packages and read some [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/) to adopt new methods and implement them in your project.

> Some concepts are changed some other dependencies and lot more is going on there. So we need to keep an eye there.

### So migrate your project and Happy Learning :)

Comment: I was facing the these kind of issues earlier, read docs and that resolved my problems

Comment: My old code that I mentioned worked well until few month ago... which part did you follow from the document???

Comment: And VScode doesn't throw any error from my code after I upgrade firebase(cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8)

Comment: either dont update packages and code, just go and fin out errors and cofigure firebase according to it if possible OR update packages and code according to latest docs.

Comment: Portion of documentation to follow is depends on error you are having

Comment: Firebase packages follow different approach to work in every version (i saw them). If you have updated them, they might cause problem somewhere